# statfs showing same output for all pathname

Tags: c, linux

Can any one please find out the problem  in this code.
Problem is its showing same output for all pathnames ,even though they have different contents,different files.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>  
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/vfs.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])  
{
    struct statfs sb;
    if((statfs(argv[1],&sb))==0)
    {
            printf("optimal transfer blk size is %d\n",sb.f_bsize);
            printf("total data blocks are %d\n",sb.f_blocks);
            printf("free blocks in fs are %d\n",sb.f_bfree);
            printf("total file nodes in fs are %d\n",sb.f_files);
            printf("free file nodes in fs are %d\n",sb.f_ffree);
    }
}

[testuser@hdchshocms6344 ex4]$ ./a.out /home/testuser
optimal transfer blk size is 4096  
total data blocks are 8819390
free blocks in fs are 6771045  
total file nodes in fs are 2240224  
free file nodes in fs are 1927385 

[testuser@hdchshocms6344 ex4]$ ./a.out /home/testuser/harish
optimal transfer blk size is 4096
total data blocks are 8819390
free blocks in fs are 6771034
total file nodes in fs are 2240224
free file nodes in fs are 1927386
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`statfs` gives information for mounted *filesystems*, not directories. Unless `/home/testuser/harish` is a different filesystem altogether (i.e. you have mounted a partition at that location), it is expected and normal that you get the exact same information as for `/home/testuser`.